# GTX 970 bandwidth calculation

Tags: gpu, gpgpu

I am trying to calculate the theoretical bandwidth of gtx970. As per the specs given in:-

http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-970/specifications

Memory clock is 7Gb/s
Memory bus width = 256

Bandwidth = 7*256*2/8  (*2 because it is a DDR)

```
      = 448 GB/s
```

However, in the specs it is given as 224GB/s

Why is there a factor 2 difference? Am i making a mistake, if so please correct me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clock rate reported is an "effective" clock rate and already takes into account the transfer on both rising and falling edges. The trouble is the factor of 2 for DDR.

Some discussion on devtalk here: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/995384/theoretical-bandwidth-vs-effective-bandwidth/

Comment: Thank you you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The 7 Gbps seems to be the *effective clock*, i.e. including the data rate. Also note that the field explanation for this [Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units&oldid=789093717#Field_explanations) says that *"All DDR/GDDR memories operate at half this frequency, except for GDDR5, which operates at one quarter of this frequency"*, which suggests that all GDDR5 chips are in fact quad data rate, despite the DDR abbreviation.

Finally, let me point out this note from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_Nvidia_graphics_processing_units&oldid=789093717#GeForce_900_series), which disqualifies the trivial `effective clock * bus width` formula:

> For accessing its memory, the GTX 970 stripes data across 7 of its 8 32-bit physical memory lanes, at 196 GB/s. The last 1/8 of its memory (0.5 GiB on a 4 GiB card) is accessed on a non-interleaved solitary 32-bit connection at 28 GB/s, one seventh the speed of the rest of the memory space. Because this smaller memory pool uses the same connection as the 7th lane to the larger main pool, it contends with accesses to the larger block reducing the effective memory bandwidth not adding to it as an independent connection could.

Comment: "DDR/GDDR memories operate at" - wrong. Internal real memory banks inside chip operate at low frequency (bus divided by some value), and I/O part of chip operates at bus frequency. Effective data rate is not GHz, it is Gbps (per pin, should multiply with bus width to get total bandwidth). With GDDR5 effective rate is bus frequency *4; with DDR3 = bus*2.

Comment: @osgx Indeed, thanks for correcting me - the "Gbps" unit is not such a nonsense after all, I've edited my answer. As for the "DDR/GDDR memories operate at" part, it is a literal quote from Wikipedia, so feel free to fix the source.

Comment: "operate at" part was not from good article about DDR, it was just to convert GHz of memory bus to GB/s. There in memory were slow core clock, bus clock and effective data rate (SDRAM/DDR/DDR2): https://www.gamereplays.org/community/uploads/post-535-1156446279.gif. GDDR5 have additional clocks: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GDDR5_SDRAM "differential command clock (CK) & differential write clock (WCK)  (WCK01 and WCK23)" And GDDR5X can work at dual and qual rates: "option to use either a double data rate mode that has a prefetch of 8n, or a quad data rate mode that has a prefetch of 16n."

Comment: Table for SDRAM-DDR4: https://www.transcend-info.com/Support/FAQ/FAQPics/DDR.JPG and http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9783319023809-c1.pdf "Table 2.3 GDDR comparison" from "Chapter 2. An I/O Line Configuration and Organization of DRAM" - High-Bandwidth Memory Interface. Kim, Lee, Song. 2014

Answer (score -1):

In fact, your format is correct, but the memory clock is wrong. GeForce GTX 970's memory clock is 1753MHz(refers to https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/geforce-gtx-970.c2620).